# How Can I Add Country Flags to Django Phonenumber Widget

Tags: python, django

I have used django-phonenumber-field in my project with Babel which is working fine with drop down of all countries with their international dialing code.
My problem is that I want each country flag attached to their names so that the phonenumber field will be smaller.
Attached is the what I presently have. [image]

This is exactly what I want to achieve with django-phonenumber-field.
[image]

And you can observe that my phone number fields are two; one has the international code and the other field is where the phone number is to be entered whereas I want all in one field with Countries Flags.
Anticipating your prompt answer, thanks.